# Замена строк в файле

Tags: php

```
<?php

$for_edit  = "подробнее"; // искомая строка 1
$for_edit2 = "подробнее2"; // искомая строка 2
$what      = "кратко"; // на эту меняем

$fopen = @file("21.txt");
foreach ($fopen as $key => $value) {
    if (substr_count($value, $for_edit)) {
        if (isset($fopen[$key + 1])) {
            array_splice($fopen, $key + 1, 1, $what);
        }
    }
    $f = fopen("21.txt", "w");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fopen); $i++) {
        fwrite($f, $fopen[$i]);
    }
    fclose($f);
}
?>
```

Скрипт ищет определённую строку и меняет следующую на нужную, как сделать, чтоб скрипт искал 2 определённые строки и всё, что между ними, менял на нужную строку? (Чёт не получается отформатировать текст.)

Comment: а примерить регулярку не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBetween($s1, $s2, $str)
{
    $s = strpos($str, $s1) + strlen($s1);
    $e = strpos($str, $s2);
    return substr($str, $s, $e-$s);
}
echo getBetween('<img ', ' />', '<img src="lalala.gif" alt="lalala song" />');
```

Как заменить, думаю, догадаетесь? =)

Comment: Если можно, то напишите как. Я только начал изучать пхп.

Comment: [str_replace][1]'ом.

[1]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: А можно в готовом виде? Я тогда лучше пойму.

Comment: Гм... У вас есть две строки, между которыми ищете: `$s1` и `$s2`, строка, в которой ищете: `$str` и замена: `$rpc`. Код будет выглядеть так:

    $q = getBetween($s1, $s2, $str);
    $str = str_replace($s1.$q.$s2, $s1.$rpc.$s2, $str);

Но это все при учете, что у вас действительно в `$str` встречается `$s1` и `$s2`.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, функция которая находит и заменяет все совпадения между искомыми строками:

```
function replaceBetween($s1,$put,$s2,$str){
$s = explode($s1,$str);
foreach($s as $k=>$r){
$n=strpos($r,$s2);
$out .= ($n?$s1.$put:($k?$s1:'')).substr($r,$n);
}
return $out;
}
//использование в вашем случае:
echo replaceBetween($for_edit,$what,$for_edit2,file_get_contents('21.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (весь скрипт расписывать не буду, думаю разберетесь):

```
$text; // содержимое нашего файла
$str1; // Строка 1
$str2; // Строка 2
$to_r; // Текст на который будет меняться информация между строкой 1 и 2

preg_replace('#('.$str1.').*('.$str2.')#msi', '$1'.$to_r.'$2', $text);
```

Comment: регулярки вещь хорошая, но опасная.. попробуй заменить "x" в строке "/asd;)x(" на чтонибудь. имеется ввиду текст между ")" и "("

Comment: Just try it ;-)

    $text = "/asd;)x(";
    $text = preg_replace("#(\/asd\;\))x(\()#", '$1text$2', $text);
    echo $text;
    
На самом деле, ничего более гибкого, чем регулярные выражения, я еще не встречал для обработки текста. Кроме этого, я часто работаю с большим объемом информации и регулярные выражения дают очень хорошее преимущество в скорости...

Comment: пустоту возвращает.. так и должно быть? и следуя вашему примеру должно выглядеть так: preg_replace('#()).*(()#msi', '$1text$2', $text);

Comment: Прошу прощения. Парсер съел текст:
$text = preg_replace("#(\\/asd\;\))x(\()#", '$1text$2', $text);

Comment: Вот... Уже начали управляющие символы экранировать, еще чуть-чуть и будет работающая регулярка ;) 
Регулярки - очень хороший и гибкий инструмент, но, повторюсь, использовать его надо крайне аккуратно.

Comment: Управляющие символы были экранированые в самом начале) Написал же - съел парсер)

Использовать его нужно не аккуратно, а правильно) И все, достаточно один раз разобраться с регулярными выражениями что бы потом можно было их использовать повсеместно в проектах)