# Как извлечь данные из файла по маркеру?

Tags: php

Мне нужно из текстового файла взять только ту часть, где между ними есть маркеры, например, есть текст, нужно взять только ту часть, что находится между `<<pop` и `<<pop`.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужны регулярные выражения. Но можно попробовать, например так:

```
echo "Ваш идентификатор: ".session_id()."</br>";
    $mystring = "12345 рвораыв <<pop Нужный текст1 <<pop 657890 Текст какой-то <<pop Нужный текст2 <<pop";
    $content = split("<<pop", $mystring); // "первый параметр - разделитель", второй - сама строка
    // возвращает массив
    echo $content[1];
    echo $content[3];
```

Comment: `split` она DEPRICATED, так что лучше использовать `explode`

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `substr`:

```
$input = "xxx <<popSomeText<<popcorn";
$marker = "<<pop";
$pos1 = strpos($input, $marker);
if ($pos1 !== FALSE) {
    $pos1 += strlen($marker);
    $pos2 = strpos($input, $marker, $pos1);
    if ($pos2 !== FALSE) {
        $output = substr($input, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1);
    }
    else {
        die("не найден маркер конца");
    }
}
else {
   die("Не найден маркер начала");
}
echo $output, "\n";
```

Можно через `preg_match`:

```
$input = "xxx <<popSomeText<<popcorn";
$marker = "<<pop";
if (preg_match("/\Q$marker\E(.*)\Q$marker\E/",$input,$match)) {
    $output = $match[1];
}
else {
    die("маркеры начала/конца не найдены");
}
echo $output, "\n";
```

Но тут нужно понимать что `(.*)` и `(.*?)` будут работать по-разному, можно [узнать больше про регулярные выражения](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

Answer (score 1):

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36729/замена-строк-в-файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36729)